# How can you get a "SWTException: Invalid thread access" here?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am registering a lifecycle listener in the `plugin.xml`. It runs ok if I just define a `Shell`.
e.g.

```
@PostContextCreate  
void postContextCreate(final IEventBroker eventBroker){  
     System.out.println("CALLED!");    
     final Shell shell = new Shell(SWT.TOOL | SWT.NO_TRIM);  
     shell.open();  
     eventBroker.subscribe(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.ACTIVATE, new EventHandler() {  

    @Override  
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {  
        System.out.println("Closing shell");  
        shell.close();  
        shell.dispose();  
        System.out.println("Closed");  
        eventBroker.unsubscribe(this);  
        }
     });
```

But if I change the call to also use a `Display`:

```
@PostContextCreate
void postContextCreate(final IEventBroker eventBroker){  
    System.out.println("CALLED!");  
    Display display = new Display();  
    final Shell shell = createSplashShell(display);  
    shell.open();  
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {  
    if (!display .readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();  
    }
    display.dispose ();  
   //etc
```

I get the following exception:

> org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException:
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread   access     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:229)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:206)
>     at

I understand that this exception has to do something with the `UI` thread but I can not figure out how using `Display` causes this exception here.
Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my understanding, I see that you want to popup a shell when an event occurs.
One display( created by main RCP app) is enough to crate new shell and processing events.

```
@PostContextCreate
    void postContextCreate(final IEventBroker eventBroker){  
        System.out.println("CALLED!");

        final Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
        { 
         final Shell shell = createSplashShell(display);  
         shell.open();  
         while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {  
         if (!display .readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();  
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: This main `Display` is the one that loads the `Parts` and `Window` of the application?

Comment: I think you better should brush up on Display and Shell and SWT GUI stuff :). Display is a class that is used for communication between underlying native OS and resource management.

Comment: :I am new in Eclipse RCP and these concepts seem (for me) hard :(

Answer (score 5):

Use the [Display.asyncExec](http://www.jdocs.com/swt/3.2/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html?m=M-asyncExec%28Runnable%29#M-asyncExec%28Runnable%29) method to execute a Runnable on the UI thread.

Like most UI frameworks, SWT doesn't let any thread act on the UI components, so when you have something to change from another thread, you must give it to this utility which executes it on the UI thread.

Comment: But I can not understand how `Display` causes this.Could you describe how to refactor the code? Put the `new Display` as part of `Display.asyncExec`?

Comment: Why are you creating a second Display instead of reusing the current ? I don't think that RCP allows that.